# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile DOCKER problem

Tags: docker

I started learning Docker today and I can't pass this problem i get in Visual Studio Code. My code looks like this:

[image: CODE]

And I've done everything according to tutorials, but it still won't work. It's not the extension, it's not the wrong file.. Can someone help?

Comment: Please, remove the image and paste your code into the editor. If we're going to help then we may need to try your code and we don't want to have to copy type it from an image.

Comment: You can `COPY JVKdA.png .` into a Docker image, but it won't be runnable.  Please see [ask] in the SO Help Center for some style guidelines; it's much better to paste the text of your Dockerfile and the text of the error message than a screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the `docker build .` command from `FIRST-DEMO-DOCKERIZED` folder.